# How do I dynamically add a control within a PanoramaItem?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dynamic, windows-phone, panorama-control

I am using Visual Studios 2010 to make a Windows Phone 7 app, and I'm trying to understand how to dynamically create a CheckBox within the grid of a PanoramaItem when the user pushes a specific button.

The following code successfully adds a check box to the main grid called "Layout Root":

```
private void addItemButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
    box.Content = "Test Box";
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(box);           
}
```

However, I want to add the check box to a specific location, namely the grid of a PanoramaItem (titled "Pan2"). Is there a way to do that, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The same way you added it to LayoutRoot:

```
Pan2.Children.Add(box);
```

Given that `Pan2` is an actual Grid control inside a `PanoramaItem`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I get the following error:
Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PanoramaItem' does not contain a definition 
for 'Children' and no extension method 'Children' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PanoramaItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need a `Grid` inside the `PanoramaItem` - notice what I mentioned at the end of my post.